# sample-rate on pulseaudio changing by itself (resolute)

Tags: pulseaudio

I have a problem to configure the sample-rate of my external sound card (fostex usb audio hp-A4 stereo numerique (IEC958)) on my linux computer with pulseaudio:

```
> uname -a
Linux music 6.5.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.5.3-1kali2 (2023-10-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux

> pulseaudio --version
fostex usb audio hp-A4 stereo numerique (IEC958)
```

The file ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf has been modified to have a high sample-rate at 192000 (Hz):

```
> cat ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf
...
default-sample-format = float32le ; s16le
default-sample-rate = 192000
alternate-sample-rate = 192000
...
```

Everything was OK before an update, but now I can see an LED on my external sound card indicating 192000 for 10 seconds, and then it changes to 48000.

I can had some details (with results of those commands playing some music with VLC at the same time):

```
> pacmd list-sinks
Aucun démon PulseAudio en cours d’exécution, ou ne s’exécutant pas dans une session de type démon.
> pulseaudio -D 
> pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
        name: <auto_null>
        driver: <module-null-sink.c>
        flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: IDLE
        suspend cause: (none)
        priority: 1000
        volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 1773.77 ms
        max request: 3000 KiB
        max rewind: 3000 KiB
        monitor source: 1
        sample spec: float32le 2ch 192000Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stéréo
        used by: 0
        linked by: 0
        configured latency: 2000.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
        module: 14
        properties:
                device.description = "Sortie factice"
                device.class = "abstract"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

some more details again:

```
> pactl list sinks
Destination #52
    État : RUNNING
    Nom : alsa_output.usb-FOSTEX_FOSTEX_USB_AUDIO_HP-A4_00001-00.iec958-stereo
    Description : FOSTEX USB AUDIO HP-A4 Stéréo numérique (IEC958)
    Pilote : PipeWire
    Spécification de l’échantillon : s32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Plan des canaux : front-left,front-right
    Module du propriétaire : 4294967295
    Sourdine : non
    Volume : front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Volume de base : 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Source du moniteur : alsa_output.usb-FOSTEX_FOSTEX_USB_AUDIO_HP-A4_00001-00.iec958-stereo.monitor
    Latence : 0 usec, configuré 0 usec
    Marqueurs : HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS 
    Propriétés :
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "FOSTEX USB AUDIO HP-A4"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.long_card_name = "FOSTEX FOSTEX USB AUDIO HP-A4 at usb-0000:00:10.0-1, high speed"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "32"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "FOSTEX FOSTEX USB AUDIO HP-A4 at usb-0000:00:10.0-1, high speed"
        api.alsa.card.name = "FOSTEX USB AUDIO HP-A4"
        api.alsa.path = "iec958:2"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "2"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "FL,FR"
        card.profile.device = "2"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.id = "45"
        device.profile.description = "Stéréo numérique (IEC958)"
        device.profile.name = "iec958-stereo"
        device.routes = "1"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        device.description = "FOSTEX USB AUDIO HP-A4"
        node.name = "alsa_output.usb-FOSTEX_FOSTEX_USB_AUDIO_HP-A4_00001-00.iec958-stereo"
        node.nick = "FOSTEX USB AUDIO HP-A4"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:2:iec958:2:playback"
        priority.driver = "1008"
        priority.session = "1008"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "35"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "merge"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "52"
        object.serial = "52"
        node.max-latency = "16384/48000"
        api.alsa.period-size = "512"
        api.alsa.period-num = "64"
        api.alsa.headroom = "512"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "2"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio2"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.bus-id = "usb-FOSTEX_FOSTEX_USB_AUDIO_HP-A4_00001-00"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:10.0-usb-0:1:1.0"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-usb"
        device.name = "alsa_card.usb-FOSTEX_FOSTEX_USB_AUDIO_HP-A4_00001-00"
        device.nick = "FOSTEX USB AUDIO HP-A4"
        device.plugged.usec = "31679646"
        device.product.id = "0x0011"
        device.product.name = "FOSTEX USB AUDIO HP-A4"
        device.serial = "FOSTEX_FOSTEX_USB_AUDIO_HP-A4_00001"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/sound/card2"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1019"
        device.vendor.name = "Elitegroup Computer Systems (ECS)"
        device.string = "2"
    Ports :
        iec958-stereo-output: Sortie numérique (S/PDIF) (type: SPDIF, priority: 0, availability unknown)
    Port actif : iec958-stereo-output
    Formats :
        pcm
        mpeg-iec61937, format.rate = "{ \"min\": 44100, \"max\": 352800 }"
```

Comment: If something is changing your setting behind your back, maybe that something put a notification in the logs? Can you check your logs? Besides, your setting is likely to be incompatible with your *internal* sound card. Are you sure it isn't used at all? If it was used, that would explain why the sample rate is reset to a value that is compatible with your internal sound card.

Comment: Thank you xhienne for your answer. Some questions:
- how can I see my logs? There is a special command in bash to see that?
- I think that my internal sound card is not compatible with my settings. But I don't know how to do to keep the settings on my external card (and I didn't have that problem before the upgrade). Do you have an idea to do that?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: It depends on your system and I don't know Kali Linux. If it uses systemd, try `journalctl`. Else, your logs are typically stored in `/var/log` but the files there also depends on how your system is configured.

Comment: I put the result of journalctl -r in the question. May be it can help you to tell me what to do next. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the logs you added don't say anything useful regarding your issue (besides, `bind(): Adresse déjà utilisée` -- address already in use -- seems to suggest that you ran pulseaudio while another instance was already running). The only thing I can suggest you to try is to set `alternate-sample-rate = 48000` but it's quite a wild guess as I don't know pulseaudio.

Comment: I tried `alternate-sample-rate = 48000` but the problem is still here. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you want pulse to stick with one sample rate, then both the default and alternate should be set to that same value. When you experience the problem, please check with `pacmd list-sinks` first to see what's sink sample rate **and whether the sink is running at all** (i.e., whether you are actually using the card via pulse). If it is, then the only reason I can think of is some kernel regression that prevents the card to be opened at your desired rate (or prevents the rate support from being correctly detected).

Comment: (It's relatively unlikely for pulse to have regression since it's somewhat in maintenance mode.)

Comment: Hey Tom, what I can say is that both the default and alternate are set to that same value.

Comment: I just did a `pacmd list-sinks` and put the result in my post. I can see `sample spec: s32le 2ch 192000Hz` in the result but the light of my external card still is on  48000??

Comment: You were not playing anything though, at least not via pulse. (Or, you have multiple pulse servers running for some reason.)

Comment: I did the `pacmd list-sinks`playing some music with VLC at the same time.

Comment: Yeah obviously (at least) VLC is not using pulse. You can check with `pactl list sinks` instead. (Yeah space instead of dash in between.) (No more `pulseaudio -D` btw; if it's not started, just leave it.) Since you mentioned update, my guess it's using pipewire (and its pulse server implementation, "pipewire-pulse"). See [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#Changing_the_default_sample_rate) for some pointer to changing the rate used by pipewire. If you don't see pactl give you some "expected" result, then maybe somehow VLC is using ALSA lib or so.

Comment: I put the result of `pactl list sinks` (vlc still running).

Comment: I don't think VLC is the problem because the light on my external sound card changes by itself without VLC. But may be ALSA is the problem. I saw that on some posts here about it...

Comment: Note that `pactl` is not the same as `pacmd`.

Comment: Sorry, the post is with the right entry now... We can see the rate at 48000Hz. You don't think I have to change something in ALSA?

Comment: `You don't think I have to change something in ALSA?` No, you are using pipewire. See the link I posted above. (You'll need to restart some user services after changing the configuration, I think; if you don't know which just logout and wait for 10s and re-login.) (I don't know which exactly either because pipewire is a bit more complex; and I don't have much experience with it.)

Comment: It was ok when I modified pipewire config file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the sample rate in the config file of pipewire to make it work:

first I had to install pipewire-audio ([link](https://wiki.debian.org/PipeWire))

```
> sudo apt-get install pipewire-audio
```

then I had to create a new directory and copy the config file of pipewire ([link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#Configuration)):

```
> mkdir ~/.config/pipewire
> cp /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire.conf ~/.config/pipewire/pipewire.conf
```

then editing the new pipewire.conf ([link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#Changing_the_default_sample_rate)):

```
> nano ~/.config/pipewire/pipewire.conf
...
context.properties = {
    ...
    default.clock.rate          = 192000
    ...
```

One last thing, the config file is not read when your OS starts but when you play some sounds.

Comment: `One last thing, the config file is not read when your OS starts but when you play some sounds.` This is because pipepire (or even pulse) does not start until you have logged in or played some sounds (the latter if you enabled only the socket unit; the former if you have enabled the service as well). (I think it will open the sound card for a while upon startup just like pulse.) (If you use a display/login manager, it might have its own instance of pipewire though.)